# how to insert inside quantity column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**I have a sql command that inserts a value into the table, but if that id already exists, it will insert it into the quantity column**
*I have a sql command that inserts a value into the table, but how do I do it if that id already exists it will insert it into the quantity column and add each time that id repeats*

Comment: Do a php check before update/insert, does the id already exist? If it does exits, then **update** that id with +1 on quantity column. If not then **create/insert** new row.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you connected by pdo.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]); 
$result= $stmt->fetch();

if($result){

   $sql = "UPDATE your_table SET quantity=? WHERE id=?";
   $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute([($quantity+$result['quantity']),$result['id']);

}else{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (id, quantity) VALUES (?,?)";
  $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$id, $quantity]);
}
```

Comment: No, you should use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: You are right. It's more logical and easy with a single query.